# Sending mail using C#

Tags: c#

I have to send mail using C#. I follow each and every step properly, but I cannot send mail using the code below. Can anybody please help me to solve this issue? I know it's an old issue and I read all the related articles on that site about it. But I cannot solve my issue. So please help me to solve this problem. The error is: `Failure sending mail`. I use `System.Net.Mail` to do it.

```
using System.Net.Mail;

string mailTo = emailTextBox.Text;
string messageFrom = "riad@abc.com";
string mailSubject = subjectTextBox.Text;
string messageBody = messageRichTextBox.Text;
string smtpAddress = "mail.abc.com";
int smtpPort = 25;
string accountName = "riad@abc.com";
string accountPassword = "123";

MailMessage message = new MailMessage(messageFrom, mailTo);                            
message.Subject = mailSubject;
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.Body = messageBody;
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;              
SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, smtpPort);
objSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(accountName, accountPassword);
objSmtp.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;
objSmtp.Send(message);                                
MessageBox.Show("Mail send properly");
```

Comment: yes.no problem on smtp i m sure.

Comment: your code works for me , but i have one issue , the from mail is always equal to my NetworkCredentialMail , can anyone tell me what is wrong , and how can i get the from address

Answer (score 2):

If the target mail server is an IIS SMTP (or indeed any other) server then you'll have to check the relay restrictions on that server.

Typically, you either have to configure the mail server to accept incoming relay from your machine's name (if in Active Directory) or IP address.  Either that, or you can make it an Open Relay - but if it's a public mail server then that is not recommended as you'll have spammers relaying through it in no time.

You might also be able to configure the server to accept relayed messages from a particular identity - and if this is website code that'll mean that you will most likely have to configure the site to run as a domain user so that the NetworkCredentials are sent over correctly.

Comment: If it is a relaying issue then there is no problem with the code but with the design

Answer (score 1):

oh friends...i got the solution.

just i used the port 26.now the mail is sending properly.

```
int smtpPort = 26;
```

anyway thanks to Zoltan

riad.

Answer (score 0):

> The error message you're receiving, "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required," indicates that the SMTP server you are trying to connect to requires authentication, but your client is not providing the necessary credentials. This is a common error when using email services that require authentication, especially after enabling two-factor authentication (2FA) for your email account.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MailApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((textBox1.Text != "" && textBox1.Text != null) && (textBox2.Text != "" && textBox2.Text != null)) {
                if (textBox3.Text != "" && textBox3.Text != null)
                {
                    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                    mailMessage.To.Add(textBox3.Text);
                    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(textBox1.Text);
                    mailMessage.Subject = textBox4.Text;
                    mailMessage.Body = textBox5.Text;

                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    try
                    {
                        smtp.Send(mailMessage);
                        MessageBox.Show("Email Sent","Email",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    error.Visible = true;
                    error.Text = "Please Enter the To Email Address !";
                    return;
                }
            } else
            {
                error.Visible = true;
                error.Text = "Please Enter the Mail id And Password !";
                return;
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            error.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[https://github.com/GnanaMoorthy550/Projects.git][1]